# python - how do i create a figure that fills the screen?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to show a figure on the entire screen or at least have no "white space" in the figure window. Right now I use plt.tight_layout() and get rid of some of it but note entirely. Ideally, I'd like to maximise it and get rid of any axis ticks.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(range(10), range(10))
plt.tight_layout() # <-- probably need something better here
plt.get_current_fig_manager()
mng.full_screen_toggle()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get rid of the whitespace and the axis. I'm not sure about making it full screen though. Is `mng.full_screen_toggle()` not working for you?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(range(10), range(10))
ax = plt.gca()

# remove white back ground
ax.set_frame_on(False)

# remove axis and ticks
ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

# No padding 
plt.tight_layout(pad=0)

# Make full screen
mng = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
mng.full_screen_toggle()
```

Comment: `mng.full_screen_toggle()` is working, I was interested in the other parameters the answers provide. thank you

Comment: Great, If this answers your question, please remember to accept it!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(range(10), range(10))

# hide axis:
[sp.set_visible(False) for sp in [ax.spines['top'], ax.spines['right'], ax.spines['left'], ax.spines['bottom']]]
ax.yaxis.tick_left()
ax.xaxis.tick_bottom()
ax.get_xaxis().set_ticks([])
ax.get_yaxis().set_ticks([])

# 0 pad:
plt.tight_layout(0)

# save fig:
plt.savefig("1.png")
```